# First view in RelativeLayout expand to fill remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I am working on a layout with a cardview, a checkbox and a button with the initial structure as shown in the first image:

[image: Layout with hidden listview]  [image: layout with expanded listview]

In this case the listview is not shown until the user clicks an image inside the cardview, so when this happens the dessired structure is like 
the second image

However as the listview is actually inside a fragment I can't achieve the dessired layout because wrap_content and match_parent for the cardview gives me the next result

[image]

And as you can see the cardview overlaps the button and the checkbox goes beyond the screen

Right now this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/event_invitation_expand_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/event_invitation_expand_icon"
                android:id="@+id/shrink"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_shrink"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/shrink"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/list">

            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="ListFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/card"/>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless"
    />
```

I hope you can help me to set the max height of the card view to stop growing when the space is filled.

I have also tried to set the checkbox always at top of the bottom and the cardview to fill the remaining space and although it gives me the correct structure when the listview is expanded, it doesn't work for the list hidden since the cardview fills the space with nothing.

**Update**

As suggested I have tried changing the root layout to LinearLayout using weight, however, I got the same result as before and if I change the weight of the cardview to 1 and the checkbox to 0 I am able to get the desired layout for the expanded list but not for the hidden case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:orientation="vertical">



    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            >



            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/event_invitation_expand_icon"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/event_invitation_expand_icon"
                android:id="@+id/shrink"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_shrink"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/shrink"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/list">

            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="ListFragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/check"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a `LinearLayout` and use [Weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) for the childs.
You can change all views weight on click.

But I think you'll need to put your `CheckBox` inside a layout and set this layout weight. Otherwise you'll mess with the height.
Didn't look to close to your layout, but you may need to do that for `CardView` too.
Just keep that in mind.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thnk you, I will give it a try

Comment: I have tried with the LinearLayout but still got the same problem

Comment: @ElAwDk did you use weight in childs and set their height to 0?

Comment: @ElAwDk All your direct childs need weight. Example, I have a linear layout with 2 views. Both of them have height 0, and weight 1. That means the weightSum is 2. So they will have the same height. Half the screen for one, and half for the other one.

Comment: @ElAwDk In your case, if you set Card to 1 and Check to 0. Card will take the whole screen because the sum is 0. Did this help?

Comment: Yes that solves the problem when the list is visible, but when is hidden the card still takes the whole screen but it doesn't have anything

Comment: @ElAwDk I'm sure this is the right way. I just don't know you're code, but stick to this idea and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get almost the desired behavior but just with the checkbox being always on top of the button

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are trying to do, you would have better luck using a LinearLayout with vertical orientation as your root element. Doing this, you could set the CardView to have a weight of 1 (and a 'height' of 0dp, because of how weight works) without giving a weight to the other elements, causing it to fill all available space not taken by the other two elements. The method for doing this can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with LinearLayout but still have the same problem. I have updated the code